# C++: Are common ancestry and an interface/prototype mutually exclusive features of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, interface, prototype, ancestor

In C++, does inheriting a common ancestor and inheriting an interface (and requiring definition of a method in derived classes) require multiple inheritance? Eg. do I have to do the following (instead of merging `MyInterface` and `ParentClass`):

```
class MyInterface;
class ParentClass;
class DerivedClass1;
class DerivedClass2;
class SomeOtherType;
class YetAnotherType;

class MyInterface {
  public:
    //  Must be defined in all derived classes
    virtual SomeOtherType my_common_fxn(...) = 0;
    ...
};

class ParentClass {
  private:
    //  Common ancestor
    YetAnotherType _useful_member;
}

class DerivedClass1 : MyInterface, ParentClass {
  public:
    // Do some things with _useful_member, using approach #1
    SomeOtherType my_common_fxn(...);
    ...
}

class DerivedClass2 : MyInterface, ParentClass {
  public:
    // Do some things with _useful_member, using approach #2
    SomeOtherType my_common_fxn(...);
    ...
}

void fxn_or_method_using(ParentClass);
```

Is it possible to (elegantly) merge the functionality of `MyInterface` and `ParentClass` into a single class? (I believe that as `MyInterface` is an ABC I cannot use this type as a parameter to `fxn_or_method_using`.)

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate- I've searched but none of the existing C++ questions appeared to line up. Q's and/or A's may have been over my (untrained) head.

Comment: I don't get the question. First: why would multiple inheritance be bad here? Secondly: why not just let ParentClass inherit MyInterface?

If you come from a java-background: there is no such thing as a interface in C++. You can declare virtual functions as 0 making the class abstract, but that doesn't mean you can't put defined functions in there. I.e. you can just put my_common_fxn into ParentClass with this declaration.

Comment: `fxn_or_method_using` needs to take its parameter by reference not value, and then you can declare it as referring to `MyInterfsce` if you wish.

Comment: @Klemens 1. I don't have a problem with multiple inheritance- in fact that's how my code is implemented currently. I'm looking for something more "elegant" with a single inheritance so I won't run into issues forgetting both.

Comment: @Klemens 2. My understanding is that if `ParentClass` inherits `MyInterface`, `ParentClass` will be required to implement the pure virtual method `my_common_fxn`. On one hand, if I mark `my_common_fxn()` as pure virtual, `ParentClass` becomes ABC and I cannot use it as the type for the first parameter to `fxn_or_method_using()`. On the other hand, if I do not mark `my_common_fxn()` as pure virtual it doesn't have to be implemented in derived classes.

Comment: @Alan If you write this up as an answer I'll accept it. I've looked into this more and it appears to work for me! My understanding is that by passing by reference, there is no attempt to instantiate a copy of the ABC, and therefore it can be specified as the type for the first parameter of `fxn_or_method_using()`.

Comment: @mvs No, it does not need to. If a class has a pure virtual function it cannot be instanciated, i.e. you cannot create an object of it. I.e. if ParentClass inherits a pure virtual function it is also abstract, but that would work fine if you only use DerivceClassN which implements it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your inheritance model.

But in C++ you need a pointer or reference for polymorphism. Your `fxn_or_method_using` takes its parameter by value. That has several problems. It causes slicing, it prevents polymorphic function calls, and it can't work for an abstract type because you can't create instances of those.

If you change `fxn_or_method_using` to take its parameter by reference not value, then you can declare it as referring to `MyInterface` if you wish. All the disadvantages disappear and you get the polymorphic behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks Alan- Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

No. You can mix virtual and pure virtual and concrete inheritance all from the same class in C++ with no problems.

```
class baseClass{

public:
  blah1(){
  //stuff
}
  virtual blah2();

  virtual blah3() = 0;

};

class derivedClass : baseClass
{


};
```